# O que é posição no SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, arquivo, edi

Tenho uma dúvida. Recebi o *layout* de uma tabela do qual consta:

```
Nome do campo | Tamanho | Posição | Tipo
```

A Posição contém:

```
De | Até
```

E um dos campos é:

```
Histórico ( no caso da Posição ): 35 | 104
```

O que seria exatamente essa posição?

Comment: Isso não parece ser SQL ou algo do SQL Server, isto para ser um arquivo de tamanho fixo. Passe mais informações para termos certeza e poder responder.

Comment: Então bigown. Recebi apenas um txt com essas informações, do qual contém o nome do campo, o tamanho, a posição e o tipo ( numérico, alfa, etc ). Esse txt foi exportado do sql server.

Comment: E o que você precisa fazer com isto? O que que saber?

Comment: Preciso saber o que quer dizer essa posição, pois foi exportado de uma base sql server e será importado para outra base sql server que pertence a um outro sistema. Porém o layout desse outro sistema contém essas informações do qual não estou conseguindo entender sobre a posição.

Comment: Se não me engano, acho que é a posição da linha, mas não estou seguro se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Esse txt é de cobrança, boleto ou algum afim? quem gosta disso geralmente são bancos, ex: do caracter 0 até 6 é a informação sobre a agência, 7 ao 14 sobre a conta e assim vai.

Comment: Na verdade é de uma tabela de lançamentos de um programa de contabilidade. Essa posição não seria a posição dentro do banco de dados?

Comment: Não, acredito que seria posição dos caracteres, cada linha do arquivo seria algo assim linha 1 `20938429836721638217478563875349577` linha 2`33938429836721638217478563875349577`. Em teoria todas linhas teriam o mesmo comprimento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É a posição da coluna. Pelas descrições este é um arquivo de tamanho fixo, então cada coluna de dados está sempre na mesma posição da linha. Então a primeira coluna obviamente está na posição 0 da linha. A segunda coluna está na posição 0 mais o tamanho da primeira coluna. A terceira coluna é a posição anterior mais o tamanho da coluna anterior. Então com o nome e onde começa cada coluna você pode manipular isto da forma como for mais conveniente para você.

Se for fazer programação certamente usará muito *substring*, mas o SQL Server tem um importador que permite dizer onde estão estas posições e ele mesmo corta cada coluna e importa corretamente, desde que os dados estejam em ordem, claro.

No caso do `de` e `até` significa a posição inicial na linha onde começa a coluna e onde termina. Então 35 significa que terá que pular 34 caracteres iniciais da linha para começar pegar um dado que seja desta coluna (`Histórico`) e vai pegar todos os caracteres até a posição 104.

Essa [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10293301/221800) tem uma passo a passo mostrando o funcionamento do importador.

Comment: Acho que seria interessante colocar um link que ensine o passo-a-passo da importação. Vai poupar ele de ter que elaborar um programa ou coisa do tipo só pra fazer a importação.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, a dúvida não parece ser especificamente sobre SQL Server. Parece ser sobre layouts de importação e exportação. Vou responder e depois veremos as *tags* apropriadas para colocar a pergunta.

Um layout é um arquivo de dados bem sintetizado que tem coisas assim:

```
GAJ07123456789060720301149915072000583922180003801    00000000003427759000000547    000001AA 06     
GAJ07256704671015072030114991507200058876543210380    00000000006759542000000547    000002AA 06     
GAJ07256704671015072030114991507200058392218000380    00000000006463264000000547    000003AA 06     
GAJ07256704671015072030111234507200058392218000380    00000000004181042000000547    000004AA 06     
GAJ07256712234315072030114991507200054567218000380    00000000005645190000000547    000005AA 06     
GAJ07256704671015072030114991507200058392278900380    00000000007419465000000547    000006AA 06
```

Ou seja, humanamente não é fácil ler ele, mas ele pode ser lido com a ajuda de um **documento de layout**, que é isso que você tem em mãos. Repare que todas as linhas têm o mesmo comprimento.

Este cabeçalho aqui ajuda a ler as linhas de baixo:

```
Nome do campo | Tamanho | Posição | Tipo
```

Indicando pra você o nome do campo em questão, quantos caracteres ele tem, em que posição da linha ele começa e em que posição termina.

Pegando como exemplo:

```
Histórico (Posição): 35 | 104
```

Considerando uma linha como estas que coloquei de exemplo, você vai ler a *substring* da posição (coluna) 35 até a posição (coluna) 104 de cada linha.

Experimente pegar um arquivo exportado e abrir no Bloco de Notas ou qualquer editor de texto que identifique a linha e a coluna do cursor.

Comment: Provavelmente é uma exportação de dados da base para algum arquivo que precise ser enviado para algum órgão ou banco. Uma tag apropriada seria EDI (Electronic Data Interchange) que é o modelo padrão de mercado para troca de arquivos de informação do tipo posicional.

Comment: @MarcosRegis [Pode colocar sua sugestão aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4439/tag-para-arquivos-de-texto-de-exporta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-importa%C3%A7%C3%A3o), por favor?

Comment: Coloquei lá. Uma coisa importante a ser incluida na resposta é que para a criação deste tipo de arquivo é necessário usar muito o *padding* e o *alinhamento* de acordo com o tipo do dado. Dados textuais sempre serão alinhados à esquerda com preenchimento de espaços em branco à direita enquanto numéricos serão alinhados à direita com preenchimento de zeros à esquerda, por isso que no layout que o autor da pergunta colocou possui a informação de tipo.

Comment: @MarcosRegis Então, esse tipo de informação normalmente a gente coloca no Wiki da tag. Como a tag ainda não existe, apenas estou esperando um tempo pro pessoal opinar, e aí criamos a tag.