# Retirar espaços de um arquivo texto

Tags: php, string, arquivo

Como faço para retirar os espaços de um arquivo texto? Tenho o seguinte arquivo texto:

```
LC1 00019   1 31012012          00001                              00243206
```

Dei um upload e coloquei o seguinte código:

```
$abrirArquivo = fopen($uploadArquivo, "r");
    while(!feof($abrirArquivo)){
        $ler = fgets($abrirArquivo,460);
        $quebrar = explode(" ",trim($ler));
        print_r($quebrar)."<br>";       
    }
    fclose($abrirArquivo);
```

Porém quando dei um `print_r()`, apareceu dessa forma:

> Array ( [0] => LC1 [1] => 00001 [2] => [3] => [4] => 1 [5] => 31012012
>   [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] =>
>   [15] => 00001

Observem que muitas chaves ficaram sem valores. Como faço para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Como vc quer ler a string? pq o explode por espaço?

Comment: na verdade preciso pegar apenas algumas informações desse arquivo texto. Por ex.: preciso do 31012012 e 00243206. Dei um explode para quebrar e pegar dentro de um array, porém estou esbarrando com esse desafio.

Comment: Pode usar o número do indíce, `3` e `5`, ex, `echo $quebra[3] .'#'. $quebra[5];`  é continuação [dessa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92537/91)?

Comment: perdão rray, não entendi sua pergunta...

Answer (score 2):

Você está lendo um arquivo com dados de tamanho fixo, então tem que acessar as posições, não pode usar `explode`, nem mesmo supor que o espaço é separador. Pode não ter espaço entre dados diferentes, pode ser que o espaço faça parte do dado. Esquece essa lógica. teria que ser algo assim (dá para melhorar):

```
$abrirArquivo = fopen($uploadArquivo, "r");
while(!feof($abrirArquivo)){
    $ler = fgets($abrirArquivo,460);
    $campo1 = trim(substr($ler, 0, 4));
    $campo2 = trim(substr($ler, 4, 8));
    $campo3 = ...;
    ...
}
fclose($abrirArquivo);
```

Não adianta pegar atalhos. O que poderia fazer para simplificar é colocar os tamanhos ou posições em um *array* e fazer uma laço para automatizar tudo isto. Algo assim:

```
$tamanhos = { 4, 8, 2, 18 ..... };
$abrirArquivo = fopen($uploadArquivo, "r");
while(!feof($abrirArquivo)){
    $ler = fgets($abrirArquivo,460);
    $campos = array();
    $posicao = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($tamanhos); $i++) {
        $campos[] = trim(substr($ler, $posicao, $tamanhos[$i]));
        $posicao += $tamanhos[$i];
    }
}
fclose($abrirArquivo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/RemoveSpaces.php).

Comment: Aquela função `scanf` não faz algo parecido?

Comment: Não. Pode até ser que consiga neste caso, mas é o acerto pela coincidência. O que ele tem aqui (e eu sei também porque ele já fez outra pergunta sobre o assunto) é um arquivo de tamanho fixo, qualquer algoritmo que pegue a informação de outra forma, está conceitualmente errada e e só funcionará por coincidência.

Answer (score 2):

Para remover os espaços em branco, use `array_filter()`:

```
$abrirArquivo = fopen($uploadArquivo, "r");
    while (!feof($abrirArquivo)) {
        $ler = fgets($abrirArquivo,460);
        $quebrar = explode(" ",trim($ler));
        $quebrar = array_filter($quebrar, function($var){return !is_null($var);});
        //print_r não necessita de "echo"
         print_r($quebrar);
        //se deseja converter para uma string, basta fazer um implode pelo separador:
         echo implode("", $quebrar);
    }
fclose($abrirArquivo);
```

Entretanto, não entendi porque você converteu sua string em array, se você só deseja remover os espaços do conteúdo de um arquivo e mostrá-lo, basta fazer isso:

```
$data = file_get_contents('seu_arquivo.txt');
$saida = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $data);
```

Se deseja escrever no arquivo, edite sua pergunta para que isso fique mais claro. Agora se quer pegar alguns valores desse array, basta acessar o índice, por exemplo, para pegar 31012012, `$quebrar[5]`.

```
$quebrar = explode(' ', $saida);
```

Para todas as linhas:

```
foreach ($quebrar as $linha => $valor) {
    //aqui a posição da linha
    echo $linha . '<br>';
    //aqui o valor da linha
    echo $valor . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta. O meu arquivo texto ele traz com um espaçamento muito grande como postei acima, porém ao testar os códigos, vi que as posições podem variar. Teria algum modo de retirar esses espaçamentos e colocar apenas um espaço entre eles, do qual ficasse mais fácil de pegar em array sem erros? Por LC1 0019   1 31012012 00001 00243206

Comment: é só mudar para: echo `preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $data);` ou no método acima: `echo implode(" ", $quebrar);`

Comment: Perfeito. Usei o data = file_get_contents('seu_arquivo.txt');
echo preg_replace('/\s+/','', $data); Retirou todos os espaços, colocando apenas um espaço entre cada palavra. Agora como faço para pegar por exemplo uma das palavras? Ex.: LC1 00001 1 31012012, gostaria de pegar somente o 31012012.

Comment: A resposta para essa pergunta já está escrita.

Comment: Desculpe Ivan. Tem razão. Não havia percebido. Seu código funcionou perfeitamente, mas para fechar com chave de ouro, ele está me retornando só a primeira linha.... tem algum meio de retornar todas as linhas?

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace("#[^0-9|A-Z]#", "", $var);
```

Comment: Note que na pergunta ele quebra os elementos em várias partes. Falta quebra-los para sua resposta estar completa. Ou certa.

Comment: Isso me parece mais um trecho de código.